# Transliteration issue

Tags: iphone, ios, transliteration

*La> ila>ha illAlla>hu wah}dahu> la> shari>ka lahu, lahul mulku wa lahul h}amdu, wa huwa ‘ala> kulli shai’in nadir.

This is transliteration of ayah. The font used is Times New Arabic . After applying this font i didn't see any changes.Characters like ">" didn't disappears. any solution?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
NSString *ayah = @"La> ila>ha illAlla>hu wah}dahu> la> shari>ka lahu, lahul mulku wa lahul h}amdu, wa huwa ‘ala> kulli shai’in kadir.";

ayah = [ayah stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">"                                     
                                       withString:@""];

ayah = [ayah stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}"
                                       withString:@""];
```

Comment: sir actually these(">" or "}") character are used to make their look different when Times New Arabic font is applied,but after applying this font no change in font occurs.

Comment: does iphone support "Times New Arabic font" ?

Comment: when other fonts are applicapable then "Times New Arabic" would also have to be applicable in same manner as others.

Comment: i think u should check first that does iphone support Times New Arabic or not.

Comment: Do you know sir any other font type/family which will support this transliteration text.if yes then sir tell me the name.Thanks

Comment: sorry buddy i dont know of any translietration fonts for arabic

Comment: @Moxy anyone else who can help me????

Comment: @MehmoodHassan Try adding a font yourself to your app. One you know would support this transliteration. (It shouldn't be hard to find on google or StackOverflow how to add a custom font to an iOS app)